# I just updated a CMS page, which of the numerous caches should I flush to see the changes?

Tags: cms, cache

As the title suggested I have made some updates to a CMS page and was trying to avoid clearing all of my caches and indexes. I googled but did not find a clear concise explanation for which caches cleared what.. any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blocks cache.
And layout cache if you added some custom layout to the page.
Also if you have a full page cache that might need refresh if there is no way to delete the FPC for a single page.

Comment: hey marius, what is means by FPS?

Comment: @AmitBera It's FPC not FPS and it means F(ull)P(age)C(ache).

Comment: Blocks cache! I knew that one applied to Static Blocks but didn't realize it also applied to CMS, thanks